# Django ForeignKey.limit_choices_to with ForeignKey to ManyToMany scenario

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-q

I have a complex relation scenario as shown below. I'd like `limit_choices_to` `Questions` that are related to `JobChecklistAnswer.job_checklist.checklist` on `JobChecklistAnswer.question`.

How can I filter those `Question`s as [Q object (or callable as the docs say)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)?

```py
class Checklist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(_("description"), max_length=150)


class Question(models.Model):
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(Checklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(_("question"), max_length=200)


class Job(models.Model):
    ...
    ...


class JobChecklist(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(Checklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class JobChecklistAnswer(models.Model):
    job_checklist = models.ForeignKey(JobChecklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # FIXME: Add limit_choices_to query question
    question = models.OneToOneField(ChecklistItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.TextField(_("answer"))
```

Comment: You can not limit the choices with this. You will need to limit the choices in the form where you present the options.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the OneToOneField "reverse" relation, a ForeignKey "reverse" relation returns a QuerySet.

You are not returning a queryset here in the OneToOneField, You are only reversing a relation between them

So the first step is to change OneToOneField into a ForeignKey

then you can use limit_choices_to attribute on **ForeignKey**

Comment: Not a problem to convert that to `unique=True` FK but still couldn't find a way to write the queryset for `limit_choices_to`